# How to replace "NaN" values while importing a csv file to Oracle table using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, numpy

I have this `airport.csv` file and I'm trying to insert these values to an Oracle table.
(Here is the small chunk of data for reference!)

```
4 code                               AAN
lat                              24.25
lon                              55.75
name                    Al Ain Airport
city                     Ayn al Faydah
state                        Abu Dhabi
country           United Arab Emirates
woeid                         12523371
tz                          Asia/Dubai
phone                                0
type                          Airports
email                            BLANK
url                              BLANK
runway_length                      NaN
elev                               NaN
icao                              OMAL
direct_flights                      12
carriers                             9
Name: 4, dtype: object
5 code                             AAQ
lat                             44.9
lon                          37.3167
name                Olkhovka Airport
city                    Novorossiysk
state             Krasnodarskiy Kray
country                       Russia
woeid                       12516605
tz                     Europe/Moscow
phone                              0
type                        Airports
email                          BLANK
url                            BLANK
runway_length                    NaN
elev                             NaN
icao                            URKA
direct_flights                    24
carriers                          15
```

But it seems these file has some "NaN" values in it which are causing some problem while inserting.

Mainly, runway_length and elev are the columns having "NaN" values.

I've been trying to fix this in different ways.   But nothing's really working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle import DatabaseError
try:
    #create connection
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('airport/pratik997@//localhost:1522/xe')
    print('connected!')

    #create cursor()
    c = conn.cursor()
    data = pd.read_csv('D:\\github repo\\python\\airportfiles/airport.csv', usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18], index_col=False)
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
#         insert = """insert into airport(code,lat,lon,name,city,state,country,woeid,tz,phone,type,email,url,runway_length,elev,icao,direct_flights,carriers) values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18)"""
#         c.execute(insert, tuple(row))
#     print('records inserted!')
    
#         print(row)
#         if(row['runway_length']=='NaN'):
#             row['runway_length']==0

#         elif(row['elev']=='NaN'):
#             row['elev']==0

        print(row['runway_length'].replace('NaN', '0'))
        print(i, row['elev'].replace('NaN', '0'))
    
except DatabaseError as e:
    err, = e.args
    print("error occured!", err.code)
    print("error msg", err.message)

finally:
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

I don't want "NaN" values instead I want "0".
Please! Can somebody help with it?

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas has a function called fillna for this purpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

I suggest manipulating a copy of the "data" dataframe using this function before inserting it into your database.

```
data.fillna('0')
```